# Learning JSON. Dreamweaver says there is an error in line 2. Cannot find it

Tags: json, syntax-error, dreamweaver

I'm trying to make a list in JSON. I'm using a tutorial I found on the internet and it seems to have a syntax error in it. I have no previous experience with JSON and I cannot figure out why this code shows an error. Line 2 in particular.

```
{
"quizlist":[


    {
    "question":"Portuguese is spoken in _______",
    "option1":"Brazil",
    "option2":"Argentina",
    "option3":"Ecuador"
    },
    {
    "question":"What is the capital of Peru?",
    "option1":"Lima",
    "option2":"Bogota",
    "option3":"San Juan"
    },
    {
    "question":"Which country is long and thin?",
    "option1":"Chile",
    "option2":"Uruguay",
    "option3":"Colombia"
    }

]}
```

I am using Dreamweaver CS6 as I am trying to create this for a website.

Thank you.

Comment: jsonlint.com says it is a valid JSON

Comment: it is saying JSON is good,double check your json, http://www.jslint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON is fine. I have an intuition that you are trying to use this JSON as it is in html.You need to save the JSON as a javascript object. Try this:

```
var myJSON = {
"quizlist":[


{
"question":"Portuguese is spoken in _______",
"option1":"Brazil",
"option2":"Argentina",
"option3":"Ecuador"
},
{
"question":"What is the capital of Peru?",
"option1":"Lima",
"option2":"Bogota",
"option3":"San Juan"
},
{
"question":"Which country is long and thin?",
"option1":"Chile",
"option2":"Uruguay",
"option3":"Colombia"
}

]};
```

Then you can use this Javascript object `myJSON` wherever you want to use the JSON data.

Hope it helps .. :)

Comment: Thank you. This solved the error. Yet I'm still not getting the element I need on the website preview. I'll raise another question as it is related to JSON but not this particular topic.